# Login to facebook without registering as an app?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, dashboard, facebook-login

I am quite new to the facebook app thing. I have read a lot around; I have read about facebook connect, graph, FQL but it seems i can find a way to login a user without him/her verifying my app. Is it possible to implement a facebook dashboard like hootsuite without registering as an app?

Thanks
Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope , I dont think so you can do , because face book verifies your app-id and shares the user-id by validating your app id and secret key . So  we need to specify while using SDK  appid and secret key some what like this

```
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId'  => '2312312313123',
            'secret' => 'asdaaff12434314asdr14112',
    ));
```

With out this none of the face book users attributes could be accessed .